# Можно ли сделать эталонную строку без добавления в ресурсы strings.xml?

Tags: android, строки, locale

У меня приложение имеет такие локализации: `Английская` и `Русская`. Приложение клиент-серверное и получает данные с сервера соответственно. Ситуация такая - при одном из запросов у меня приходят строки на языке которого нету в ресурсах, а именно на немецком, и дальше уже я кривым способом сравниваю пришедшую строку с строкой указанной в коде, и при соответствии я подменяю отображаемый текст на определенную локализацию. Пример:

```
text = if (statusFilter[2] == "nicht beworben") {
resources.getString(R.string.record_status_16)
} else {
statusFilter[2]
}
```

и таких кусков где-то 20 штук и есть приблизительно три участка где используется такая вот кривая конструкция. Мне кажется это совсем не правильно, хотя этот способ и работает. У меня есть три варианта решения данной проблемы:

1. Добавить немецкую локаль в приложение, но тогда придется переводить все приложение а это довольно трудозатратно и сейчас этим вряд ли кто-то будет заниматься.
2. Добавить как-то подобие эталонных строк, чтобы я с ними сравнивал и дальше уже брал из ресурсов строки определенной локали. Я что-то видел такого плана, называлось по-моему константы или как-то так, но я не очень понял как сделать при помощи этих констант.
3. В отдельно созданный класс, слать массив стартовых строк на немецком языке и дальше уже сравнивать с элементами этого массива то что приходит. То есть будет действовать при принципу ресурсов для одного языка, без нужды переводить все приложение.

Как вы посоветуете поступить и как вообще поступают в таких ситуациях?

Comment: 1. Не понятно как это поможет, если строка и так на немецком, а для других её всё равно надо костылять-переводить.

Comment: @woesss, этот способ просто один из вариантов, он как-бы рабочий тоже, но сам по себе не очень хорош)

Comment: Может я чего не понял - если приложение работает на русском, строка приходит на немецком, то чем поможет добавление немецкой локали... Ну да ладно, как-то не приходит на ум более оптимального решения - в любом случае вам же нужно каждое место сравнить со своей строкой, и взять из ресурсов тоже конкретную строку. Мне думается это наименее затратный вариант. Единственное но - если со стороны сервера строки изменятся, придётся искать и исправлять все эти куски, поэтому может быть удобнее вынести сами строки в константы (это просто `static final` поле) в одно место.

Comment: то есть вы считаете что самый простой вариант - добавить новую локаль для приложения?

Comment: Нет я считаю оставить как есть, только можно литералы (`"nicht beworben"`) вынести в константы в одно место. В Котлине они выглядят как-то так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729715

Comment: я не совсем понял как все должно работать, но вам не обязательно переводить все приложение на какую то локаль. можно перевести только нужные строки, тогда недостающие будут браться из локали по умолчанию (папки /values без идентификаторов)

Comment: я за первый способ

Comment: @pavlofff, насколько я знаю студия не сможет сформировать установщик если нету локалей для всех ресурсов, поэтому я и задумался над какими-то константами или чем-то типа такого

Comment: Сможет, только линт будет ругаться, и ошибки добавятся по соответствующем количестве не достающих элементов (переводов). Или как вариант можно будет в каждую не переводимую строку добавить: tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" или  translatable="false". Какой из них лучше, выбирать вам. Я за первый и второй способ, как говор woesss, в котлине делается это через "companion object" или можно писать за рамками класса (я создаю для этого отделиный файл), ещё можно использовать enum, будет вам своеобразный тип констант.

Comment: Проще эту проблему решить с Вашим бек-ендером, есть пару вариантов:  1. при запросе отправлять вашу текущую локаль, тогда сервер будет возвращать Вам текст на нужном языке! 2. Ввести понятие код сообщения, и по этому коду показывать нужную строку.